# How to create default type in an atom using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

I am trying to create an atom for an object. I get the following error under default in the atom: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Country | RecoilValue | Promise | Loadable | WrappedValue'.
Property '[WrappedValue_OPAQUE]' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'WrappedValue'.ts(2322)
How can I fix this? I am new to typescript.

```
export interface Country {
  capital: string;
  continents: string;
}
```

```
import { Country } from "../types/country";
import { atom } from "recoil";

export const countryAtom = atom<Country>({
  key: "countryAtom",
  default: {},
});
```

Comment: Give it a default value? `default: { capital: "Washington, D.C.", continets: "North America" }` for example. Also "continents" is spelled incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the type during the atom creation:

```
export interface Country {
  captial: string;
  continets: string;
}

export const countryAtom = atom<Country>({
  key: "countryAtom",
  default: {
    captial: "example string 1",
    continets: "example string 2",
  }
});
```